# How to get PHP to create HMAC-SHA1 strings like Objective-C?

Tags: php, objective-c, sha1, hmac

I am trying to implement an authentication solution with PHP and Objective-C. Both languages create their own HMAC-SHA1 encoded strings with the same key and the same secret.

Apparently they seem to differ in their way how they do it.

On Objective-C side I am using OAuthCustomer as signing class which produces the correct looking encoded string:

```
/3n/d4sKN6k3I7nBm1qau59UukU=
```

On PHP side I am using the built-in function hash_hmac('sha1',...) with base64 encoding which produces this:

```
ZmY3OWZmNzc4YjBhMzdhOTM3MjNiOWMxOWI1YTlhYmI5ZjU0YmE0NQ==
```

Then I have tried to use another function (mentioned [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php#39492)) and this produces with base64 encoding this:

```
NWY1ODUwOWE3NGI4NWU5ZTIxMDYzMTNmNzk3NTYxMDQ4OWE1MmUzNQ==
```

I have absolutely no idea how I can fix this issue and I don't even know why this happens.

Thanks a bunch for help,

Paul

Comment: The output of `hash_hmac()` is a hex-string. You've base64_encoded that hexstring, which is probably wrong. Set the 4th param to hash_hmac to true first.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it but the output wasn't really different (keys and secrets are dynamic so it changed a little bit): N2ZmYWNlZjc2YjYwZGIzMzA0ZjBmMDhiNDhkMzUyNTJhYjViYTY1Nw==

Comment: No, you didn't. That's still a hexstring when decoded.

Comment: You're a genius. I changed the 3rd value of the md5 function to true because I missed a bracket. Now it works as it is supposed. Thank you! :)

Comment: @mario: Make it an answer, get some points!

Comment: @GregS: Christmas laziness. **Also**: you have just three more points than me! :}

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, I'll add a faux answer. (On Stackoverflow every question should be decorated by an answer.)

The hash functions in PHP mostly return hex-strings, not the real data. (For whatever reason). There is usually a function parameter to make it compatible to what other implementations expect:

```
 hash_hmac("sha1", $data, $key, $raw_output=TRUE);

 md5($str, $raw_output=TRUE);

 hash("sha1", $data, $raw_output=TRUE);
```